# jQuery simple getJSON doesn't work

Tags: jquery, json

I want to load a simple json file and display it's content but it doesn't work, I don't know why :(

Nothing is displayed on console.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('/api/?core=users&function=getJson', function(data) {
  var items = [];
    console.log("ok!");
  $.each(data, function(key, val) {
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
  });

  $('<ul/>', {
    'class': 'my-new-list',
    html: items.join('')
  }).appendTo('body');
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="my-new-list">
<li>test</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON datas loaded are :

```
{"fruit_name":"Tomato"}
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thank you !

Comment: What is returned in your console?

Comment: Nothing is returned on console :/

Comment: And in `console.log(data);`?

Comment: I tried. But nothing :(

Comment: If yo use chrome check , network tab in debugger mode, result is :

`0: {undefined: 23}`
`1: {undefined: 34}`

Check your json schema.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If nothing is displayed in the console, then the success function is never getting fired.

Either your server request is returning something other than 200 (like 404, 500, etc) OR the string you're returning is not valid JSON.

Check your network tab to see what is coming back from your request. If it's coming back as 200, then the string you're returning isn't a valid JSON string.

Validate it at: jsonlint.com

Comment: I agree with this idea.

Comment: On the network tab, the json file is successfully loaded with code 200. Mime type application/json.

Comment: jsonlint.com returns "Unexpected token" for my api json URL :/

Comment: Give us your JSON URL

Comment: There are two invisible characters at the beginning of your string. Not valid JSON. Check your server-side scripts to see how they could've gotten in there (maybe at the beginning or end of one of your PHP files). I've seen this happen before but the causes aren't always the same.

Comment: Delete the server-side code and re-type it by hand. If the problem persists, delete the entire file and re-type it. most likely the characters came from wherever you originally copied the code from.

Comment: $array = array("fruit_name" => "Tomato"); echo json_encode($array); (UTF-8 file)

Comment: Nobody is disputing that that line is correct, what we're saying is that somewhere in the script(s) that are being executed when you make that call, there are two invisible characters (most likely occurring before an opening <?php tag (I always omit the closing ?> tag of a php file for this exact reason - to prevent invisible characters at the end from getting outputted). As @KevinB suggests, delete the file and retype that part, DO NOT COPY AND PASTE, as you'll just be taking the characters with you when you do so.

Comment: I've deleted the closing ?> tags. Retyped the array part and check that nothing else is displayed. Same error.

Comment: Remember, that might not be the only file that is executed during that call. By looking at the URL you are probably going through an index.php gateway and that is including certain other files. The problem could be occurring in any or all of the files that are getting executed when you make that request.

Comment: Yes there is a index.php file, that include three config files, and the api file. I've checked all.

Comment: The problem exists in one of those files. I guarantee it. Feel free to copy the code (between the <?php tags ?>) out of those files and into new files and then just add your own opening <?php tag to the file (so you aren't copying the very beginning of the file, which is likely where the problem is. Finally, make sure that when you upload the new files you're uploading them in AUTO or ASCII mode.

Comment: Ok, so I rewritted a raw file "test.json", and I hand-typed the json content. It works :/ I don't know the problem with php json_encode.

Comment: I tested again with a very simple "json.php" file, but with array and json_encode. It works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You have to be sure that your JSON file ( *which is regarded in getJSON()* ) is accessible and has no any errors.

Then use the following snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
        $.getJSON('/the/path/to/theJSON',{
          format: "json"
        }).done(function(data){
          alert(data.fruit_name);
        });     
      });
```

Comment: No alert is displayed. Nothing in console :x

Comment: Compare the snippet that I regarded with your code, you have not used `done()`. Here I suppose that your JSON resource is accessible and errors free.

Comment: Yes, I've created a new file with your code instead of mine. No alert is displayed.